# Can I get data from a label from one VC and pass the data to a textfield from another VC

Tags: swift

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var DestViewController : ProfileUpdateViewController = segue.destination as! ProfileUpdateViewController
        DestViewController.NameTextField.text = Namelbl.text
    }
```

Comment: have you given segue a identifier?

Comment: Yes I did, but it gives out error optional found nil when unwrapping something. What I want is the label gets the data from an API Response and want to pass that data to a textfield from another VC